# How to subtract values by comparing columns from two datasets?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data structure:

```
pos.c1<-seq(from=1,to=100,by=1)
map.c1<-seq(from=0,to=1,length.out = 100)
cro.c1<-rep(1,100)
pos.c2<-seq(from=1,to=80,by=1)
map.c2<-seq(from=0,to=1,length.out = 80)
cro.c2<-rep(2,80)
c1<-cbind(cro.c1,pos.c1,map.c1)
c2<-cbind(cro.c2,pos.c2,map.c2)
map<-rbind(c1,c2)
colnames(map)<-c("Chr","Pos","CM")

Pos.1<-c(30,52,60,72,80,4,12,30,40)
Pos.2<-c(40,53,71,79,95,9,20,35,79)
Chr<-c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4))
Data<-cbind(Chr,Pos.1,Pos.2)
```

Two dataframes.

map: with three variables. Chr, Pos and CM.
Data: with three variables: Chr, Pos.1, Pos.2

Matching Data$Pos.2 and Data$Pos.1 with map$Pos, I need to get the difference of map$CM values between these two matches. This procedure needs to be done by $Chr.

As an example: For the first row of Data (1,30,40) the desirable value would be 0.1010101 (this is obtained by the operation 0.39393939 – 0.29292929). for the first row of Data with Chr = 2 (2,4,9) the desirable value would be 0.06468352 (0.1026582-0.03797468).

Comment: What have you tried so far that it doesn't appear to work for you?

Comment: To tell you the truth I'm not quite sure how should I start...

Comment: Please also add what the expected result should look like (basically manually calculating the result).

Comment: Just did that. Its in as an example. The first row of Data should get the result 0.1010101. The sixth row would be 0.0646835. Perhaps should I edit it with all the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether I well understood what you desire, I think you have to do something like this:

```
pos.c1<-seq(from=1,to=100,by=1)
map.c1<-seq(from=0,to=1,length.out = 100)
cro.c1<-rep(1,100)
pos.c2<-seq(from=1,to=80,by=1)
map.c2<-seq(from=0,to=1,length.out = 80)
cro.c2<-rep(2,80)
c1<-cbind(cro.c1,pos.c1,map.c1)
c2<-cbind(cro.c2,pos.c2,map.c2)
map<-rbind(c1,c2)
colnames(map)<-c("Chr","Pos","CM")

Pos.1<-c(30,52,60,72,80,4,12,30,40)
Pos.2<-c(40,53,71,79,95,9,20,35,79)
Chr<-c(rep(1,5),rep(2,4))
Data<-cbind(Chr,Pos.1,Pos.2)
```

Using library `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
```

You have to tranform your data into dataframes:

```
Data <- as.data.frame(Data)
map <- as.data.frame(map)
```

Then you have just to retrieve information using `left_join`

```
Data_CM <- left_join(Data,map,by=c("Chr","Pos.1"="Pos")) %>% 
    rename(CM.1=CM)
Data_CM <- left_join(Data_CM,map,by=c("Chr","Pos.2"="Pos")) %>% 
    rename(CM.2=CM)
```

The `Diff` variable will compute the difference between two retrieved values

```
Data_CM <- Data_CM %>% 
    mutate(Diff=(CM.2-CM.1))
```

Comment: Awesome. It works perfectly. Just one question. What is %>% for?

Comment: As a practice I would like to do it by myself using loops and formulas... How should I start. Do yo know where I should look to learn how to do it? Thanks

Comment: The %>% (a.k.a: pipe) is an operator in R, typical of tidyverse packages.
For more information I suggest you to read: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial